# output string using java textfield.setText() by using for loop

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextfield, parseint

The question is, I try to make second textfield (textFieldGen) to print out the exact result likes console. Currently, second textfield shows one string only.

This is my first coding on java GUI. 
(extra info, I built it using Eclipse with WindowBuilder + GEF )

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class PassGenerator {
private JFrame frmPasswordGenerator;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PassGenerator window = new PassGenerator();
                window.frmPasswordGenerator.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PassGenerator() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmPasswordGenerator = new JFrame();
    frmPasswordGenerator.setTitle("Password Generator");
    frmPasswordGenerator.setBounds(100, 100, 419, 229);
    frmPasswordGenerator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    final TextField textFieldGen = new TextField();
    final TextField textFieldPass = new TextField();

    textFieldPass.setBounds(74, 60, 149, 19);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(textFieldPass);

    Label labelPass = new Label("Password Length:");
    labelPass.setBounds(74, 33, 177, 21);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(labelPass);

    Button genButton = new Button("Generate");
    genButton.setBounds(262, 60, 86, 23);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(genButton);
    // Add action listener to button
    genButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Execute when button is pressed
        //System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            String getTxt = textFieldPass.getText();
            boolean y = true;

            do{
                try{
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(getTxt);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    String[] alphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","w","x","y","z"};
                    int nc = 0-c;
                    int c2 = c/2;
                    int nc2 = 0-c2;
                    int ncm = (nc+1)/2;

                    if (c%2 == 0){
                        for(int x = nc2; x<0;x++){
                            int alphaNum = r.nextInt(26);
                            System.out.print(alphabet[alphaNum]);
                            String alpha = alphabet[alphaNum];
                            textFieldGen.setText(alpha.toString());
                            int numNum = r.nextInt(10);
                            System.out.print(numNum);
                            textFieldGen.setText(Integer.toString(numNum));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        for(int x = ncm; x<0;x++){
                            int alphaNum = r.nextInt(26);
                            System.out.print(alphabet[alphaNum]);
                            String alpha = alphabet[alphaNum];
                            textFieldGen.setText(alpha.toString());
                            int numNum = r.nextInt(10);
                            System.out.print(numNum);
                            textFieldGen.setText(Integer.toString(numNum));
                        }
                        int numNum = r.nextInt(10);
                        System.out.print(numNum);
                        textFieldGen.setText(Integer.toString(numNum));
                    }
                    y = false;
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e1 ){
                    int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Integer only", "Error!!", messageType);
                    y = false;
                }
            }while (y);
        }
    });          

    Label labelGen = new Label("Generated Password:");
    labelGen.setBounds(74, 109, 149, 21);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(labelGen);


    textFieldGen.setBounds(74, 136, 149, 19);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(textFieldGen);

    Button copyButton = new Button("Copy");
    copyButton.setBounds(262, 136, 86, 23);
    frmPasswordGenerator.getContentPane().add(copyButton);  
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `textFieldGen.setText (textFieldGen.getText () + "\n" + Integer.toString(numNum))`

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov if I want to reset the genButton everytime I click it, what should I add on the addActionListener? Because It appends the result when I click it again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you are setting the contents of the text field twice. I would just do:

```
int alphaNum = r.nextInt(26);
System.out.print(alphabet[alphaNum]);
String alpha = alphabet[alphaNum];
//textFieldGen.setText(alpha.toString());
int numNum = r.nextInt(10);
System.out.print(numNum);
//textFieldGen.setText(Integer.toString(numNum));
textFieldGen.setText(alpha + Integer.toString(numNum));
```

In general it is not a good practice to replace the entire text when all you want to do is append some characters to the text field. If you don't like the above then you can do:

```
textField.setText(alpha);
...
Document doc = textField.getDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), Integer.toString(numNum), null);
```

Edit:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        add( textField );

        textField.setText( "testing: " );

        try
        {
            Document doc = textField.getDocument();
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "1", null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkJue, then post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. I can't guess exactly what you did. See my edit for an example of an SSCCE.